# Troubleshooting wireless network connection: DNS not working

Tags: networking, wireless, dns

I have a wireless router that assigns IPs using **DHCP**.  My laptop (**Acer Aspire 1 110L** running **Ubuntu 10.10**) connects to the wireless network, but DNS is not working.  I've tried to trouble shoot the problem following various tutorials on [ubuntu help](http://help.ubuntu.com), but I'm stuck.

(My laptop works fine with other wireless networks, and other computers can connect to the Internet using the router in question.  My laptop worked fine with this router until a few weeks ago.  Unfortunately I don't know what changed to cause the problem.  I tried booting into various older kernels that are still on the system, but that didn't fix the problem.)

I can connect to the wireless network.  The network manager applet indicates the connection is successful.

> ifconfig indicates that my computer is assigned an IP address (192.168.0.105).

`/etc/resolv.conf` contains one line:

> nameserver 192.168.0.1

netstat -nr indicates that I have a default route to 192.168.0.1

I can `ping 192.168.0.1`, and my laptop (i.e., `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.0.105`).  I can't ping other names (e.g., `www.askubuntu.com`) or addresses (e.g., `64.34.119.12`).

What should I do next to try to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: is `nslookup` working?

Answer (score 3):

**/etc/resolv.conf** contains your **DNS** listings. 192.168.0.1 is obviously the router in question. You need to manually provide the nameserver(s) provided to you by your isp. You can usually get this information under the router/status page. In your case the router is not a nameserver and therefore will not resolve DNS.

Network-Manager will overwrite the /etc/resolv.conf to accomadate dhcp configured connections. Playing around with mixed static and dhcp connections can sometimes trigger this file to be overwritten. You could also try letting network-manager have another shot by manually restarting networking.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

We can also try to resolve the problem directly utilizing dhclient.

```
$ sudo dhclient -r
$ sudo dhclient
```

Comment: I love you. Let me double your points.

Comment: `dhclient`did it for me. Much appreciated, thank you for your answer!