# wired resolves dns but wireless dont

Tags: wireless, networking, dns

My wireless won't resolve dns but my wired connection does.

I've tried:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and:

```
$ sudo dhclient -r
$ sudo dhclient
```

as I saw at that [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/34983/48468). But it didn't solved. Any thoughts on what might been happening or which logs I gotta see to know why is it not solving dns?

sorry about the question like this, but I'm really newbie at ubuntu.

When I try to `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254`
I can see my wired connection and the modem itself but I can't see my wireless connection.

```
$ sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-06-29 16:21 BRT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1  <-- modem
Host is up (0.0027s latency).
MAC Address: 7C:4F:B5:88:C3:DE (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.135  <-- wired connection
Host is up.
Nmap done: 254 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 4.55 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal

Type

```
gksu gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

And add these lines after

> nameserver 127.0.0.1

```
nameserver 4.2.2.1
nameserver 151.197.0.38
nameserver 67.138.54.100
```

Save the file and close the editor. Then type

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Now ping to test your connection

```
ping -c 10 askubuntu.com
```

Now it should work. Flush DNS cache by typing

```
sudo aptitude install nscd
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Please do it only, when you are connected by wireless.